# Clearing user defaults programmatically in a OS X application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm working at the beta version of my App and i need to be sure that at first launch of the final release users that have been beta tester will start the application with a completely clear user default set... (i can't change the Bundle ID).

**1)** Is there a way to clear user defaults programmatically ?

**2)** Will sandboxing this App for the App Store submission helps me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it like this:

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

To run it on your first launch, I would just set a BOOL flag. One way to do it is as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFihishLaunching
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"secondOrMoreTimeLoading"]boolValue]==0) //so if there is nothing there...
    {
        NSLog(@"This is the first time the user has loaded the application. Welcome!");
        //run the code above here, then change our flag to 1 so that it never runs this again (unless the prefs are reset elsewhere)
        [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1] forKey:@"secondOrMoreTimeLoading"];
    }
    else{NSLog(@"Welcome back, user.");}     
}
```

Comment: do i need to set a specific entitlement for this operation ?

Comment: and I wouldn't sandbox anything for an App Store submission. Good luck!

Comment: @MatterGoal Nope, you should be good to go by running this on your first load. If you have trouble running the code above, another way to do it is to `removeObjectForKey` for every key, or replace your `NSUserDefaults` with an empty dictionary. What I listed above should work though.

Comment: Thank you @James how can i check for the "first launch" ? i used to set NSNumber parameter in my user defaults something like "first-launch" and check it.

Comment: Is Sandboxing a requirement for the new submissions? isn't it ? i'm pretty sure that i have read something about this argument.

Comment: it works like a charm!  (i'm working in OSx not in iOS thus i've added your code in "applicationDidFihishLaunching").

Comment: Whoops! I guess I should have asked you that (or noted the tags), sorry! I will edit my post. Regarding Sandboxing, you might want to go ahead and do it - if I remember right they delayed making it mandatory until next year, but you might as well get it out of the way.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with [+[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-resetStandardUserDefaults_ClassMethod_NSUserDefaults)? If you've registered your defaults properly, this single line will reset to the registered defaults you provided.

Comment: I'm not sure this operation works as i need, i read that it sync data  before reset. I need something to completely remove informations previously created. 

From Apple documentation: 
_italic_ Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object and releases it from memory _italic_

Comment: Then it goes on to say, "A subsequent invocation of standardUserDefaults creates a new shared user defaults object with the standard search list."

Comment: I tried with this code 

    `[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];

     NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`
But in `def` i still find user generated data. 
What i missed ?